# Present value of a sequence of payments doubt

Tags: interest-rate, discounting

Assuming the nominal interest rate is greater than 0, rank the following three sequences of payments according to their present value:

Sequence "A": $90, $100, $110

Sequence "B": $100, $100, $100

Sequence "C": $110, $100, $90

A > B > C

A > C > B

C > B > A

C > A > B

B > A > C

What I did: First the B's sequence confuses me a bit because how can payment values remain the same if interest rates are greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the question. The Payment sequence is a given, someone offers you the three options. The explicit numbers offered are not implying an interest between them, this is just what is *offered*.

The question you are supposed to answer is which of the three payment sequences are best for you, under the assumption of a market with a positive interest rate.

To calculate the solution, you need to calculate the present value of each of the given sequences, and rank them according to that. The solution will be independent of the assumed interest rate p, as long as p > 0.

Comment: Thank you. So that would simply mean that if interest rates are positive, I should be getting more money for waiting longer, therefore, C > B > A is the correct option?

Comment: no, you are getting the listed amount, that's how the question is defined. Think the other way round - is money you get now more worth than money you get next year?

Comment: Ok. I'm getting really confused. I took a hypothetical interest rate - 5% and calculated all the present values. I got C as the highest.

Comment: which is correct. getting those extra 10 bucks _earlier_ is better.

Comment: so my answer is right? what I did was manually but could you give me an intuitive explanation for tackling this problem?

Comment: having money _now_ is better (=more value) than getting it next year, isn't that obvious? I don't know how to explain it better.

Comment: ok, now when you put it this way, I feel silly! Thank you. So if interest rates were negative the opposite sequence A > B > C would hold right?

Comment: @Aganju Your 2nd comment is confusing here, C > B > A is the answer to the question since the ask is to rank the 3 sequences.